# update AWS IAM policy with ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, aws-iam-policy

I got the following playbook to update IAM policy and it works fine. But it wipes out what the IAM policy has currently and replaces it with what I have. I want to just append to the policy. How do I do it?

```yaml
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Create IAM Managed Policy
    amazon.aws.iam_policy:
      iam_type: role
      iam_name: "aws_test_role"
      policy_name: "PrismaCloud-IAM-ReadOnly-Policy"
      policy_json: "{{ lookup('template','policy.json.j2') }}"
      state: present
```

Comment: Get the existing policy with [iam_policy_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/iam_policy_info_module.html#ansible-collections-amazon-aws-iam-policy-info-module) and merge the returned json with yours prior to setting the policy.

Comment: can you provide example?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/iam_policy_info_module.html#examples